# Why awaitReactions not working? | discord.js v13

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I was trying to make a marriage system, but the thing is that reaction collector isn't working at all even the both parties reacted to the emoji. There's no error at all. After executing the command, it will only showing the embed but not totally collecting the reactions and sending the reply content

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
      return (reaction.emoji.name === "" || reaction.emoji.name === "") && user.id == member.id;
}

return message.awaitReactions({filter, max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time']})
.then(collected => {
const reaction = collected.first();
if(reaction.emoji.name === "") {
                    return message.channel.send("I think **no**...");
                }

                if(reaction.emoji.name === "") {
                    marriage.findOne({
                        guildID: message.guild.id
                    },async (err, data) => {
                        if(data) {
                            data.memberID
                            data.userID
                            await data.save()
                        } else {
                            new marriage({
                                guildID: message.guild.id,
                                userID: user.id,
                                memberID: member.id
                            }).save()

                            return message.channel.send(`${user.username} and ${member.user.username} are now married!`)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
            .catch(() => {
                message.reply("No reaction after 10 seconds, operation canceled.")
            })
```

EDIT:

```
if(exist != user.id && exist != member.id) {
            const proposal = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("IMPORTANT ANNOUNCEMENT!!")
            .setDescription(`${user.username} makes a marriage proposal to ${member.user.username}.\nAre you ready to get married?`)
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setTimestamp()

            message.channel.send({embeds: [proposal]})
            .then((message) => {
                message.react("❤️")
                message.react("")
```

This is the part of the message for collection

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you show the part of message before the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `filter` and `awaitReactions` are not inside of the `.then((message) =>)` its not going to work, first you need to put it inside

```
message.channel.send({embeds: [proposal]})
            .then((message) => {
                message.react("❤️")
                message.react("")

            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return (reaction.emoji.name == "❤️" || reaction.emoji.name == "")
                && user.id == member.id
            }
return message.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 1, time: ms('10s'), errors:["time "]})
```

second the emojis are different in your `embed` and `filter` you should change it too.

```
message.channel.send({embeds: [proposal]})
            .then((message) => {
                message.react("❤️")
                message.react("")

            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return (reaction.emoji.name == "❤️" || reaction.emoji.name == "")
                && user.id == member.id
            }

            return message.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 1, time: ms('10s'), errors:["time "]})
            }).then((collected) => 
                //your codes here
            )
```